# Having a whitespace issue in Python3 coding class

Tags: python, string, whitespace

I am outputting the right code, but I am making a mistake in the whitespace after the last colon, and also between "Houston and Texas"

[image: I am outputting the right code, but I am making a mistake in the whitespace after the last colon, and also between "Houston and Texas"]

Trying to output the output given in picture. Continuing to get error code regarding how my whitespace differs. I know it is something simple I am missing.

Comment: Just add the spaces needed: `print(f'{current_time} {my_city} {my_state}')`

Comment: Add the space where you need it with  literally a plus and a space: `+ '  '`

Comment: Please don't post images of code, errors, logs, or other text; see [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the comment above, which is a bit more advanced for a beginner, the simplest solution would be to add the spaces yourself:

so change:

```
log_entry= current_time + my_city + my_state
```

to:

```
log_entry= current_time + " " + my_city + " " + my_state
```

instead of `" "` you can also use single quotes `' '`